# Determining the voltage applied to a motor from an H-Bridge

Tags: power, circuit-design, motor, dc-motor, h-bridge

I have to replace some old (no longer manufactured) H-Bridges with new ones that are preferably the same form factor. I'm trying to understand the datasheets, but I don't see where it states the voltage supplied to a brushed motor from the H-bridge.

Here is the current H-bridge: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TA8428K_datasheet_en_20100223-1136013.pdf

The following are proposed replacements:

https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TB6643KQ_datasheet_en_20110621.pdf?did=11271&prodName=TB6643KQ

https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TB6568KQ_datasheet_en_20170414.pdf?did=1282&prodName=TB6568KQ

Where on these datasheets does it indicate the voltage applied to the motor? Is it dependent on power supply voltage \$VM\$. If so, how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You get out most of the volts that you put into an hbridge; they don't regulate voltage.